# Team invites me to "answer my first question" when I already have many answers, and dismissing is far from obvious

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

I've been a member of a team for a year or so.  Recently the site added some new-user guidance, including this invitation to answer questions:

[image: screenshot]

I currently have 51 answers on that team.  The banner is telling me to do something I've already done.  Further, I needed help from another team member to find out how to dismiss it -- I clicked on "expand", which took over the page with a big list of unanswered questions and gave me a "hide" link, but "hide" just took me back to what you see in the screenshot.  Only much later and with help did I find the smaller, unobtrusive "skip for now" link at the *bottom* of the expanded pane.  (Sorry, I failed to take a screenshot of that.)

This banner is doubly counter-intuitive -- that I saw it at all, and then that I couldn't easily dismiss it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've changed the copy on that hide step to reflect that you've answered before; instead, it will read

> Add to the community by answering a question.

I'll ask Design to take a look at the "Skip for now" button placement - it definitely gets lost!

But as for even showing the step to experienced users... anecdotally (until we have usage data),  I got one of my old, unanswered questions answered by our top user in our internal team, so it definitely has benefit so far!

Comment: Copy change going out now.

Comment: Thanks.  Occasional prompts for experienced users are fine with me; the problem was being prompted for something I've already done.  I take it these notices aren't context-sensitive, then? I.e. we can't have one message for people who've never answered and a different one for people who haven't answered in a while?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear - new users (or ones with no answers) will see the prompt in your screenshot.  If you've answered, you'll see what's in my answer here.

Comment: And this new "Answer a Question" step is part of what we're calling Inline Onboarding - it's designed for new users to learn about Teams, but we're turning it on for everyone as the steps are introduced into the product.

Answer (score 1):

This should now be resolved. Please let us know if you're still experiencing the issue.